# assistance on making a deck by using dictionaries python

Tags: python-3.x

So i'm trying to create a card deck by using dictionaries.  But whenever I `print(deck)` it's not showing the keys i added into the deck.

output:

```
{'suits': 'Spades', 'values': 'Ace'}
```

---

expected output:

### should be a full deck of cards

```
import random

# deck of cards
deck = {}

suits = [{"name": "Hearts"}, {"name": "Diamonds"}, {"name": "Clubs"}, {"name": "Spades"}]

numbers = [{"name": "2"}, {"name": "3"}, {"name": "4"}, {"name": "5"}, {"name": "6"}, {"name": "7"}, {"name": "8"}, {"name": "9"}, {"name": "10"}, {"name": "Jack"}, {"name": "Queen"}, {"name": "King"}, {"name": "Ace"}]

for each in suits:
  deck["suits"] = each["name"]

for each in numbers:
  deck["values"] = each["name"]

print(deck)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys in a dictionary must be unique. If you set a key that already exists, it will be replaced. A list is a more natural structure for a deck than a dict is.

```
deck = [{'suit': suit["name"], 'value': number["name"]}
        for suit in suits for number in numbers]
print(deck)
```

Comment: I have created a deck using lists before.  But the problem i had with is was dealing the cards out and then determining who the winner was.  Can you help me out with that?

Comment: @ChamongLo you should probably ask a new question for those issues. You can deal out a card from a list using `.pop()`. Determining the winner means writing the rules of your game.

Comment: i actually have a seperate question that was already asked but no answers, but i will ask again

Comment: @ChamongLo we're a Q&A site, not a code writing service. If you're not getting answers, you probably asked for too much at once. Make sure you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try asking again. Make sure you have an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)